# ASAN detects ODR violation of vtable of class which is shared with dynamically loaded library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, address-sanitizer, one-definition-rule

I'm working on a project which has a "util" library containing stuff like logging, assertion handling etc. This is compiled into a static library with `-fPIC` added. I also have a plugin system, where the plugins are shared libraries loaded at runtime via `dlopen`. Those plugins and the main executable both use the static util library.

The problem: Now I'm getting `AddressSanitizer: odr-violation` errors when using ASAN. The issue is `size=40 'vtable for StdStreamWriter'` reported twice where StdStreamWriter is an implementation of an interface used internally in the static library.

I tried really hard to reproduce this in a MWE:

- Create a static library exposing some function
- Inside that use an interface and implementation in a std::shared_ptr
- create a shared library linking against that
- create an executable linking against the static lib and `dlopen` the shared library

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(proj)

set(sanitizer_flags "-fsanitize=address,undefined -fno-omit-frame-pointer")
string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " ${sanitizer_flags}")
string(APPEND CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS " ${sanitizer_flags}")
string(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS " ${sanitizer_flags}")

add_library(foo STATIC foo.cpp)
target_compile_features(foo PUBLIC cxx_std_14)
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
add_library(lib SHARED lib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(lib foo)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main foo dl)
```

However the issue does not occur in the MWE no matter how hard I try.

I traced the difference down to differing results in `nm -C liblib.so | grep vtable`:

- The MWE (no ODR error) shows `V vtable for Impl`
- The acutal program shows `D vtable for StdStreamWriter`

I guess the error stems from the difference `D` vs `V` which results in the vtables not being merged.

Where does this difference come from? When is this decided? I stripped down the link command for the shared library to the bare essentials (`clang++-8 -shared -fsanitize=address,undefined -o <..> <all *.o and *.so>`) but still get the `D vtable` instead of `V vtable`.

What else can I try to fix this?

Comment: I suggest to file a bug in [Asan tracker](https://github.com/google/sanitizers) (they'll ask you to repro w/ latest Clang).

Comment: I wish I could create a repro that would help me investigate and probably solve the issue. But any MWE I tried doesn't run into that `D vtable` thing

Comment: I know it's been a year but was this Clang or GCC?

Comment: It is Clang, see the second last paragraph

Comment: Could you try compiling with `-mllvm -asan-use-private-alias=1` then? I'll prepare full answer if it works.

Comment: It seems to work in our real codebase

Comment: Could you `+1` the answer then? BTW I've deleted my answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541216/transitive-symbol-visiblity-in-c/61990271) and voted to close as dup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely caused by a [known issue](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1017) in Clang's implementation of Asan which causes it to detect false ODR violations for static data with [vague linkage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html) (normally class vtables or typeinfos).

As a workaround, try compiling with `-mllvm -asan-use-private-alias=1` and maybe doing `export ASAN_OPTIONS=use_odr_indicator=1` before running your code.

If this fixes your problem, please post a comment in the aforementioned issue to increase the chance that it's fixed once and for all in upstream.